# GREP to columns along with comma seperation

Tags: grep

Im greping a  bunch of files in a directory as below

```
grep -EIho 'abc|def' *|sort|uniq -c >>counts.csv
```

My output is

```
150 abc

130 def
```

What I need is Current date (-1) and the result of grep like below to be inserted to counts.csv

```
5/21/2018 150,130
```

Comment: could add two sample input files with 2-5 lines each? that'd help in testing and suggesting a solution.. also, the grep options used `-lho` doesn't seem to be right..

Comment: Hi sandeep, These are basically dummy values. So the dummy file should look like  "abc abc abc abc abc def def def abc abc abc
abc abc abc abc abc def def def def abc def
def def abc abc abc abc abc def def def def"

Answer (score 0):

```
grep..|sort|uniq -c
|awk -v d="$(date -d '1 day ago' +%D)" 'NR==1{printf "%s",d}{printf "%s",","$1;}END{print ""}'
```

will do it.

With your example data, it gives:

```
05/21/18,150,130
```

Comment: Hi Kent,I get this error "bash: grep..: command not found..."

Comment: @Gha1d it is your original command.  basically, just pipe the  `150 abc` etc to my awk command.